# Random crashes when using kotlin coroutines

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am using a `recyclerView` to show images / videos from sdCard, like a gallery app & recently I migrated to Kotlin and tried using coroutines for background work..

However I get random crashes when I launch a coroutine, I am not able to understand the stacktrace shown by Firebase Crashlytics, it shows Class & line number where the crash occurs but not the reason for it..

Following is my `refresh()` method where the crash occurs..

```
private fun refreshGallery() {
    gridView.adapter = null
    if (actionMode != null) actionMode!!.finish()
    myAdapter = Adapter(galleryType!!, this@BaseFragment) //This is where I am getting a crash on some devices...
    ref.isRefreshing = true

    launch {
        delay(1000)
        val statusList = getMediaFiles()
        myAdapter!!.addAll(statusList)

        myAdapter!!.setEmptyView(empty)
        gridView.adapter = myAdapter
        myAdapter!!.toogleEmptyView()
        if (ref.isRefreshing) ref.isRefreshing = false
    }
}
```

This method is called in the `onCreateView()` & `swipeRefresh.setOnRefreshListener{}`

Some more info, I extend `CoroutineScope` in the Fragment, so no `Global.launch{}`

I have also tried using the `suspend` modifier to the function, changing `withContext()` to `async{}.await` but it still crashes.

Here are the Logs from Crashlytics -

```
Caused by e.b
   at com.example.fragments.BaseFragment.refreshGallery + 352(BaseFragment.java:352)
   at com.example.fragments.BaseFragment.onCreateView + 233(BaseFragment.java:233)
   at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.onCreateAnimator(Fragment.java:5)
   at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView + 2595(Fragment.java:2595)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState + 880(FragmentManagerImpl.java:880)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState + 1237(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1237)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState + 1302(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1302)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange + 2655(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2655)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated + 2609(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2609)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated + 246(FragmentController.java:246)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart + 542(FragmentActivity.java:542)
   at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart + 201(AppCompatActivity.java:201)
   at com.example.MainActivity.onStart + 189(MainActivity.java:189)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart + 1249(Instrumentation.java:1249)
   at android.app.Activity.performStart + 6873(Activity.java:6873)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity + 2687(ActivityThread.java:2687)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity + 2785(ActivityThread.java:2785)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage + 1532(ActivityThread.java:1532)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage + 102(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop + 163(Looper.java:163)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main + 6342(ActivityThread.java:6342)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run + 880(ZygoteInit.java:880)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main + 770(ZygoteInit.java:770)
```

MainActivity's `onStart()` -

```
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    try {
        NotificationManagerCompat.from(this@MainActivity).cancelAll()
    } catch (ignore: Exception) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step one should be to retrieve the obfuscation `mapping.txt` for the build in question and finding what `e.b` maps to.

However looking at the context my guess is that it maps to `kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException`, which gets thrown if a variable that has been asserted as non-null (through `!!`) actually turns out to be `null`.

Since this has nothing to do with coroutines and the code that deals with the variable in question (`galleryType`) is not included in your question further debugging is impossible.

Comment: That same exception can also be thrown if you declare a function argument to be non-nullable (like `fun foo(bar: String)`) and then call it from Java and pass a null value.

Comment: Well that worked perfectly, don't know why the exception was thrown in Kotlin, never had this in Java.. Still your answer helped me fix that :)

Comment: Presumably you never call a method on `galleryType`, so even if it was `null` it wouldnt normally throw an exception. But Kotlin tries to throw NPEs near their origin instead of when someone tries to access them for correctness.